# Unable to install MariaDB on Centos 6.5 server - "No package available" in yum although Repo is present?

Tags: centos, mariadb

I've hit upon a strange issue with a new installation of CentOS 6.5 while trying to install MariaDB.

I've included the following information and created a `MariaDB.repo` file inside the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` folder:

```
# MariaDB 5.5 CentOS repository list - created 2013-08-11 14:22 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Then, I enter the command `yum repolist all`, and it shows that this repo is enabled.

However, I then enter this command: `yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`

This outputs the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.simwood.com
 * extras: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: mirror.synergyworks.co.uk
Setting up Install Process
No package MariaDB-server available.
No package MariaDB-client available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I've rebooted the server and ran the command again and this error message still persists. What's going on?

Comment: Add `enabled=1` to the file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` which defines this repository?  Also, ensure the capitalization of the package names is correct; `yum` is case-sensitive.

Comment: I've added `enabled=1` and typed the package name in both lower and uppercase, and it still can't find the packages.

Comment: Perhaps try the full package name, `MariaDB-5.5.34-centos6-x86_64-client` and `-server`, as seen [here](http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64/rpms/)?

Comment: I've tried that, and it still comes back saying it can't be found.

Answer (score 2):

Issue the command: `yum clean all`

---

This happens because yum didn't get the new packages list from the repo server. Usually it's preceded by a message

`Yum Error: "Not using downloaded repomd.xml because it is older than what we have"`

Cleaning yum cache will force it to redownload the packages list, and consequently, recognize the packages.

If this doesn't help, you could also try cleaning some cache in `rm /var/cache/yum/.....`